# Using raycaster to select specific elements of gltf & add event listeners

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm building an interactive web app. I've loaded a glb file to a scene and now I want to add 2 functionalities:

1. `onMouseover` on one of the elements from the object I would like to change the color of that element.
2. The 3D object consists of a Texture_Group[Object3D] as shown in the console log below. The texture group are essentially 3D letters(objects) that spell out HAJDUK, but I've imported them as a grouped .glb file, I want to add an event listener so when clicked on the individual letter(object) a different link is loaded for each individual object.

My confusion is if I can do this somehow just by using raycaster or do I need to further traverse the Texture_Group and develop a sort of if else logic for that, and how to do any of those?
 I'm guessing I need to use the raycaster and traverse the scene but I'm kind of stuck. Thank you for any of your help and if I need to provide anything else let me now, it's my first question.

I've traversed my scene in the console.log with the help of some code I've found online and adjusted it a bit to my case.

This is my app.js code:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
let scene, camera, renderer, h, controls, raycaster, mouse;

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  //Camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(0, 6, 6);

  const myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

  //Renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: myCanvas,
    antialias: true,
  });
  renderer.setClearColor(0xcfd4d8);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.deviceSPixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  //Controls
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, myCanvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 6, 0);
  controls.update();

  controls.enableDamping = true;

  controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;

  controls.screenSpacePanning = false;

  controls.minDistance = -20;
  controls.maxDistance = 100;

  controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI;
  controls.enableZoom = true;

  controls.rotateSpeed = 0.3;
  controls.zoomSpeed = 10.0;

  //Lights
  const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
  scene.add(light);

  const light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
  scene.add(light2);

  //Loader
  const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.load(
    'content/hajdukzagltf.glb',
    function (gltf) {
      h = scene.add(gltf.scene);
      h.position.set(6, -2, 1);
      console.log(dumpObject(h).join('\n'));
      console.log(gltf);
    }
  );

}

init();

//Render Loop
render();

function render() {

  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

//windowResize
function windowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', windowResize, false);

//consol log traverse
function dumpVec3(v3, precision = 3) {
  return `${v3.x.toFixed(precision)}, ${v3.y.toFixed(precision)}, ${v3.z.toFixed(precision)}`;
}

function dumpObject(obj, lines = [], isLast = true, prefix = '') {
  const localPrefix = isLast ? '└─' : '├─';
  lines.push(`${prefix}${prefix ? localPrefix : ''}${obj.name || '*no-name*'} [${obj.type}]`);
  const dataPrefix = obj.children.length
     ? (isLast ? '  │ ' : '│ │ ')
     : (isLast ? '    ' : '│   ');
  lines.push(`${prefix}${dataPrefix}  pos: ${dumpVec3(obj.position)}`);
  lines.push(`${prefix}${dataPrefix}  rot: ${dumpVec3(obj.rotation)}`);
  lines.push(`${prefix}${dataPrefix}  scl: ${dumpVec3(obj.scale)}`);
  const newPrefix = prefix + (isLast ? '  ' : '│ ');
  const lastNdx = obj.children.length - 1;
  obj.children.forEach((child, ndx) => {
    const isLast = ndx === lastNdx;
    dumpObject(child, lines, isLast, newPrefix);
  });

  return lines;
}
```

console.log:

```
*no-name* [Scene]
  │   pos: 6.0000, -2.0000, 1.0000
  │   rot: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
  │   scl: 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000
  ├─*no-name* [AmbientLight]
  │     pos: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
  │     rot: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
  │     scl: 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000
  ├─*no-name* [PointLight]
  │     pos: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
  │     rot: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
  │     scl: 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000
  └─*no-name* [Scene]
    │   pos: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
    │   rot: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
    │   scl: 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000
    ├─Camera_(2) [PerspectiveCamera]
    │     pos: -12.5626, 8.9117, -9.9300
    │     rot: -0.1273, -0.2253, -0.0286
    │     scl: 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000
    ├─Texture_Group [Object3D]
    │     pos: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
    │     rot: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
    │     scl: 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000
    ├─b [Mesh]
    │     pos: 2.6200, 3.9200, -19.2000
    │     rot: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
    │     scl: 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000
    ├─z [Mesh]
    │     pos: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
    │     rot: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
    │     scl: 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000
    └─bg [Mesh]
          pos: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
          rot: 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000
          scl: 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000
```

Comment: The second goal is not clear for me, can you provide more information? About the first part, you can use [Raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster). This [example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes) implements what you described in your first goal.

Comment: @ScieCode Thanks for answering my first question I'll try to implement it today, I've edited part two of the question with more info. Hope it makes it easier to understand what I'm trying to do

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I don't know exactly how the `Texture_Group` is organized in your example, but if each individual letter consists of a single Mesh child of the `Object3D`, you can simple use the Object3D children as the target for the raycast and depending on which was intersected, you perform a callback response to that specific letter. If it's too hard to understand I can write a full answer with examples to demonstrate this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer so far but if it's not a bother please do write an example, it would make it much clearer, this is unexplored territory for me

Comment: managed to make it work? @grng3r

Comment: @ScieCode Yes, thank you for your help, took me a bit until I traversed my gltf file, but now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on the comment section, all of the functionalities can be implemented using a simple [Raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster).

In order to detect when the mouse hovers over a set of objects in the scene you can group them together in either a `THREE.Group` or `THREE.Object3D` containing children meshes.

You bind a `mousemove` event to a function that update a global variable `mouse` containing the viewport mouse position.

```
function onMouseMove( event ) {

  event.preventDefault();

  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

}
```

Inside your animation loop, you perform the raycast given the current mouse position and check if that intersects any objects contained by said group. You, then, deal with updating the color of these objects or reverting those when not intersecting.

```
function raycast() {

  raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( group.children );

  if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

    if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {

      if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );

      INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
      INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
      INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( 0xd4d4d4 );

    }

  } else {

    if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );

    INTERSECTED = null;

  }

}
```

Finally you bind a `click` event to another function that performs the desired function if an object is currently intersecting the ray.

```
function onMouseClick( event ) {

  if ( INTERSECTED !== null ) clickFunction( INTERSECTED ); // perform object operation

}
```

This [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/am16yzrs/) show those functionalities working.

Let me know if something is unclear.

---

If the objects inside your `TEXTURE_GROUP` aren't neatly organized in meshes, I suggest that you first pack each letter into a single mesh and, when traversing, you add those to an `Object3D` or `Group` if those aren't already in one.